# terraform Vnet and Subnet Modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-template-file

I have a pipeline that downloads standard Terraform modules and creates resources.

1. "Module-ResourceGroup" deploys resource group.
2. "Module-Vnet" which deploys vnet.
3. "Module-Subnet" which deploys subnets.

My problem is when I kick the pipeline for the first time my pipeline fails reason because **Module-Subnet gives me an error message that Vnet does not exist.**
However, when I run the same pipeline for a second time, my Subnets get deployed without any issues as during the first run, then Vnet gets created.

I guess I have two solutions :

1. depends_on where I can say that by subnet module is dependent on vnet module.
2. Introduce a wait of 3 mins in the subnet module before it gets executed.

Q1. why it is happening? whereas as per terraform "Most of the time, Terraform infers dependencies between resources based on the configuration given" https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/dependencies
if anything is wrong with the way I have written modules?

Q2. What is a better solution depends_on OR introduce wait

Q3. Is there any other way to fix it?

Below are my modules.

Module-ResourceGroup/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "my-resourcegroup" {
  name     = format("%s-%s",var.resource_group_name,var.env)
  location = var.location
}
```

Module-Vnet/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "my-vnet" {
  name                = format("%s-%s",var.vnet_name,var.env)
  resource_group_name = format("%s-%s",var.resource_group_name,var.env)
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = var.address_space
}
```

Module-Subnet/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "my-subnet" {
  for_each = var.subnetsconfig
    name                 = format("%s-%s",each.key,var.env)
    address_prefixes     = each.value["address_prefixes"]
    virtual_network_name = format("%s-%s",var.vnet_name,var.env)
    resource_group_name  = format("%s-%s",var.resource_group_name,var.env)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the output of a resource as the input of another resource then Terraform will understand it as an implicit dependency. For example (as you did not post all of your code):

Module-ResourceGroup/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "my-resourcegroup" {
  name     = format("%s-%s",var.resource_group_name,var.env)
  location = var.location
}
```

Module-Vnet/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "my-vnet" {
  name                = format("%s-%s",var.vnet_name,var.env)
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.my-resourcegroup.name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = var.address_space
}
```

Module-Subnet/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "my-subnet" {
  for_each             = var.subnetsconfig
  name                 = format("%s-%s",each.key,var.env)
  address_prefixes     = each.value["address_prefixes"]
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.my-vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.my-resourcegroup.name
}
```

Comment: That's fine,  But then I won't be able to use the module independently. The idea is firstly to create base infra and then deploy the environment using different backends state files. Not sure I will check it and get back to you.

Comment: Most of the time it makes no sense to have a separate module per Terraform resource. Modules work best if you combine multiple resources into one module for a specific use case. In your case you can combine those three resources into a common "network" module. And if you really want to use separate modules, you can specify `resource_group_name` and `virtual_network_name` as an input variable of the two later modules (if you extend your question with all of your module code, then i will show you how).